# How can I set default value for a filter in Ag-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I want to set a Default value to a Column filter in Ag-Grid, which is active after initialization. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/example1.html) that is on the webpage under [Filtering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/index.php) there is an input tag that is used filter with. The only change that you would need to make to this example would be to give the input an initial value with the `value=""` attribute.

Alternatively, you can use the [onGridReady attribute](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/index.php) of the gridOptions that you have set up. This attribute expects a function callback. so do something like:

```
var gridOptions{
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    ...
    onGridReady: initialFilter,
}

function initialFilter(){
    gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter("initial filter value")
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jarod Moser , the example link above is no longer valid. Can you give updated link?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using infinite model then the way to go is to set the filter model during the onGridReady function.

The setFilter takes the model that is normally provided to the getRows IDataSource call, so you can grab the object from there. For example:

```
  const filter = {filterItem :{
    "dateFrom": '2021-08-09',
    "dateTo": null,
    "type": "equals",
    "filterType": "date"
  }}
  gridApi.setFilterModel(filter);
```

The field name here is "filterItem". The grid will call the getRows with this filter and it will be shown in the display with the filter icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a couple of modifications to Jarod's answer above.

Firstly, call `initialFilter()` from `onFirstDataRendered()` instead of `onGridReady()`

Secondly, changed the code within `initialFilter()` to:

```
gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance('myColumn').setModel({ values: ['initial filter value'] });
gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
```